# how to copy one 2d array to another dynamic 2d array of strings in c

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, struct

I have my base deck (base_deck) of cards and then I move this base deck to another array that is dynamic (deck). Both decks print just fine, but when I take something from the second deck, (the dynamic deck) and assign it to something else it just always fails. (the (player[j])->cards[i] = deck[i]; ) when I use the base deck it works though. Can anyone help with this? I have been trying for days, I'm new to c, but I'm not new to programing at all. So I'm figuring it has something to do with pointers.

```
    //a#include "library.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
//functions=======================================================================================
void createPlayer();
void createDeck();
void shuffle(char **array);
void distribute();
//functions=======================================================================================
//struct==========================================================================================
typedef struct {
    char first_name;
    char last_name;
    char country;
    char *score;
    char **cards;
}player_build;
//struct==========================================================================================
//extern vars=====================================================================================
player_build (**player);
char **deck;
int num_players =0 ;
int num_rounds;
char base_deck[52][52] = {"2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "Ts", "Js", "Qs", "Ks", "As",
                              "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "Th", "Jh", "Qh", "Kh", "Ah",
                              "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "Td", "Jd", "Qd", "Kd", "Ad",
                              "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "Tc", "Jc", "Qc", "Kc", "Ac"};
//extern vars=====================================================================================
int main() {

    createPlayer();
    createDeck();
    distribute();

    return 0;
}



extern void createPlayer(){
    num_players=5;
    num_rounds=4;

    player = (player_build **) malloc(num_players * sizeof(player_build*));
    for (int i=0; i<num_players; i++){
        player[i] = (player_build*) malloc(num_players * sizeof(player_build));
    }


    for (int j=0; j<num_players; j++){
            (player[j])->cards = malloc(52 * sizeof(char*));
    }


    for (int j=0; j<num_players; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
            (player[j])->cards[i] = malloc(52 * sizeof(char));

        }
    }


}

extern void createDeck(){
    char **deck = malloc(52*sizeof(char*));
    for(int i=0; i<52; i++){
        deck[i] = malloc(52*sizeof(char));
    }


    /*char base_deck[52][52] = {"2s", "3s", "4s", "5s", "6s", "7s", "8s", "9s", "Ts", "Js", "Qs", "Ks", "As",
                              "2h", "3h", "4h", "5h", "6h", "7h", "8h", "9h", "Th", "Jh", "Qh", "Kh", "Ah",
                              "2d", "3d", "4d", "5d", "6d", "7d", "8d", "9d", "Td", "Jd", "Qd", "Kd", "Ad",
                              "2c", "3c", "4c", "5c", "6c", "7c", "8c", "9c", "Tc", "Jc", "Qc", "Kc", "Ac"};
*/

    for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++){
        deck[i] = base_deck[i];
        printf("%s", deck[i]);
    }

    //shuffle(deck);
}

extern void shuffle(char **array)
{
    int n = 51;
    srand(time(0));

    for(int sh = 0; sh < 2; sh++) {
        if (n > 1) {
            size_t i;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                size_t j = i + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (n - i) + 1);
                char *t = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

extern void distribute(){
    int num_cards = 52;
    int remove_Cards = (52%num_players);
    int num_cards_this_game = num_cards - remove_Cards;
    char **hold = malloc(52*sizeof(char*));

    for(int j=0; j < num_players; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++) {
            //printf("%d \n", i);
            //hold[i] =  deck[i];
           // printf("%s \n", hold[i]);
            (player[j])->cards[i] = base_deck[i]; // works
            //(player[j])->cards[i] = deck[i]; // doesnt work
            printf("%d player num %d num of card in deck %s \n",j, i, (player[j])->cards[i]);

        }
    }
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        //hold[i] = (player+i)->cards;
        //printf("%s",(char*) hold[i] );
        printf("\n hi");
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to copy every item, array assignment won't work

Comment: Unrelated: `char base_deck[52][52]` seems a bit too much since your longest string only requires 3 chars. `char base_deck[52][3] = {...};` would be sufficient.

Comment: You appear to be treating the base deck strings as constant values. There is no need to allocate 52 characters for every item. Just allocate the `char*`s as you do, then assign and swap the pointers like you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about initialization the array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in the function distribute() I was calling the extern deck and in createdDeck() my deck array wasn't using the extern initialization, I was initializing it again.

Also thanks for the feedback about initialization the array.